Modelling a likely unit root process with ARMA? HAC standard errors in python time series packages?
I am working on a project to forecast Canada's GDP. One of the exogenous variables for my ARDL model that I consider is the treasury spread. By plotting its ACF and PACF, I notice that it can be fitted with an MA(13) process. However, the first lag of ACF is 0.97, which is nearly a unit root process. How can I move on from here? Is there a way to model it without taking the first difference of the series (as I believe it would lose much information), and add it into my ADL model later?
Another question is that is there a way to specify python statsmodels to use Newey-West HAC standard errors or HAC standard errors while performing various tests, such as Augmented Dickey-Fuller test? The original project was done in Stata, which allows us to specify what standard errors to use, and it rejects the ADF test results for Treasury spread. But in python, it fails to reject the null hypothesis, I am not sure how we can do that in python to obtain an accurate test result.
